Koopman representation: measurability and continuity, and the unitary interpretation of ergodicity
I am trying to prove the following assertion, stated (but not proved) on pages 13-14 of Bekka, Mayer's Ergodic Theory book (https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511758898):

Proposition: Let $G$ be a locally compact group acting on a probability space $(X, \mu)$ by measure preserving transformations.
Let $T_g : L^2 (\mu) \to L^2 (\mu)$ be the unitary linear map $T_g f (x) = f (g^{-1} x)$.
Then the homomorphism $\rho : g \mapsto T_g$ is continuous in the strong operator topology on $\mathcal U (L^2 (\mu))$.

My question is:

Question: Given the hypotheses of Proposition 1, how does one show that, for every $f_1, f_2 \in L^2 (\mu)$, the function $g \mapsto \int_X T_g f_1 (x) f_2 (x) \,\mathrm d \mu (x)$ is measurable?

Context:
This is the setting for interpreting ergodicity by using unitary representations.
I completely understand why $T_g$ is a unitary linear map of $L^2 (\mu)$, so I don't need help with that.
Apparently the conclusion of the question is enough to prove that the homomorphism is continuous in the strong operator topology, see this question.
If I understand correctly, in the answer there, the homomorphism $\rho$ is extended to a sort of compactly supported group algebra, and also to an integrable group algebra, and the extension is shown to be continuous.
Then it is shown that this extension is actually intertwining the left regular action of $G$ with the given action (i.e. $\rho$) on $L^2 (\mu)$, and the continuity of the left regular action is somehow pushed onto $\rho$.
Even though I did not fully read the answer, it is completely plausible and I am willing to believe it.
My thoughts on my question:
If the function $\alpha : G \times X \to X$ given by $(g, x) \mapsto g^{-1} x$ were measurable, then one could compose it with $f_1$ to get a measurable function $T_g f_1 \circ \alpha$.
Then one can also multiply the two measurable functions $(g, x) \mapsto f_1 (g^{-1} x)$ and $(g, x) \mapsto f_2 (x)$ to get a measurable function $(g, x) \mapsto f_1 (g^{-1} x) f_2 (x)$.
Integration over $x \in (X, \mu)$ should presumably yield a measurable function then.
The first problem is, I don't know if $\alpha$ is measurable or not.
Is this a consequence of the hypotheses?
The second problem is, does integrating a measurable function of two variables over one variable produce a measurable function of the other variable?
Something similar is involved in the proof of Fubini's theorem, but I don't know the technicalities there that well either.
Note: After some Googling, I found one source (lecture notes by Jesse Peterson) which call this homomorphism the Koopman representation, but this does not seem to be a very standard terminology.

Measurability of $\alpha$ is probably an unstated assumption.

Perhaps unrelated, but why do you need that $g \mapsto \int_X T_g f_1 (x) f_2 (x) ,\mathrm d \mu (x)$ is measurable?

Bekka and Mayer do assume the measurability of $(g,x)\mapsto gx$. It is written in their Definition 1.1.

@P.P.Tuong thanks for pointing that out, I missed it.

@JohnB The $g \mapsto \int_X T_g f_1 (x) f_2 (x) ,\mathrm d \mu (x)$ being measurable is a hypothesis of the general theorem on continuity of groups acting on Hilbert spaces.

I see. My point is that to characterize ergodicity (which seems to be your main interest here) I don't see why we should need measurability.
